# Show that $\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{|z|=r}{f(z)\over z}dz=2\pi if(0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb{C}\to \Bbb{C}$ be continuous at $0$. Show that $\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{|z|=r}{f(z)\over z}dz=2\pi if(0)$.

I barely saw anything like that. In fact, I had a difficult time finding references for Complex Analysis topics regarding complex continuous functions that don't have to do with (n?)either analyticity or holomorphicity.

My only problem, at this point, seems to be showing formally that $f$ is bounded on $|z|=r$ for sufficiently small $r$.

Regardless of that, under the assumption that for sufficiently small $r$, $|f|$ is bounded on $\{z:|z|\le r\}$ by M, I let $$\lim_{r\to 0}|\int_{|z|=r}{f(z)\over z}dz|\le\lim_{r\to 0}\max_{|z|=r}({f(z)\over r})2\pi r=2\pi f(0)$$
where $M$ is the maximum of $f(z)$ on the whole disc given by $r$ sufficiently small.

Could you guid me through this problem?

Though the question is not quite different from the one to which it was claimed to be identical in theory, I had not derived much from the answers, despite asking for explanations there myself, and I cannot make my misunderstanding a public thing, unless I either make another question or start a bounty.

How is an absolute value of an integral an indication to the value of the integral itself? The value of the integral itself can be multiplicated by a branch of functions whose absolute value is 1.

Comment: For sure $f$ must have other properties, too, given that $\frac f z$ is integrable on the unit circle. What are they? I believe that $f$ is taken to be continuous on a whole neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: @AlexM. how can one be sure this function is integrable? I often see mentioning of holomorphicity properties when using integration steps. Is continuity around zero and change of variables sufficient? If I find the limit for the absolute value of this integral, what does it mean regarding the integral itself?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous on some neighbourhood of $0$, then there exist a small enough $r_0 > 0$ such that for all $r \le r_0$ the circle of center $0$ and radius $r$ is contained in that neighbourhood. This means that $f$ (and therefore $\frac f z$) is continuous on all these circles, therefore $\frac f z$ is integrable on them. If the limit of the absolute value of the integral is $0$, then the limit of the integral itself is $0$; If the limit of the absolute value of the integral is *not* $0$, then you don't have much to say about it.

Comment: If I were to show that the limit is $2\pi f(0)$, could anyone say this is impossible? Because according to the guidelines, it seems like the limit is not definite...